# Formula matching dates and dividing across columns

Tags: r

I have two data frames which I am trying to create new data from.

Colnames of df 1:

```
"year_t"   "data_t"   "data_t_1" "data_t_2" "data_t_3"
```

Colnames of df 2:

```
 "year"       "multiplyer"
```

I am trying to divide by the data in `df2`. Take the data and match them firstly by the correct year, divide `data_t` by the corresponding years `multiplier` in `df2`, then take `data_t_1` and divide it by `multiplier year - 1`, take `data_t_2` and do the same `multiplier year - 2`.

```
output_t = data_t / multiplier
output_t_1 = data_t_1 / multiplier - 1 (year)
output_t_2 = data_t_2 / multiplier - 2 (years)
output_t_3 = data_t_3 / multiplier - 3 (years)
```

That is (using the first row of `df1`);

```
  year_t data_t data_t_1 data_t_2 data_t_3
1   2012 146123   162991   308060   406563
```

Using 2012 data in `df2`

```
2009    98.2319416221847
2010    100.000000000000000000000000000000
2011    103.196146412241
2012    105.720324344817
```

I am trying to get the following;

```
df1$output_t <- 145123 / 105.720324344817
df$output_t_1 <- 162991 / 103.196146412241
df$output_t_2 <- 308060 / 100.000000000000000000000000000000
df$output_t_3 <- 406563 /  98.2319416221847
```

Which is the same as saying;

```
output_t = data_t / multiplier (for year 2012)
output_t_1 = data_t_1 / multiplier - 1 (year 2011)
output_t_2 = data_t_2 / multiplier - 2 (years 2010)
output_t_3 = data_t_3 / multiplier - 3 (years 2009)
```

Data frame 1:

```
structure(list(year_t = structure(c(18L, 16L, 3L, 7L, 21L, 15L, 
2L, 21L, 2L, 17L, 17L, 3L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 14L, 13L, 
14L, 16L, 21L, 12L, 11L, 19L, 17L, 2L, 5L, 15L, 19L, 19L, 9L, 
17L, 19L, 8L, 14L, 4L, 18L, 16L, 17L, 4L, 19L, 15L, 17L, 8L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 6L, 15L), .Label = c("1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", 
"1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", 
"2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", 
"2015", "2016", "2017"), class = "factor"), data_t = c(146123L, 
824675L, 78601L, 338308L, 12321527L, 301767L, 261683L, 20810L, 
438264L, 420102L, 54325L, 1557915L, 6229156L, 3312145L, 6577744L, 
1633416L, 475845L, 851586L, 658845L, 6216087L, 2069090L, 28046L, 
622088L, 244276L, 1796582L, 7607498L, 2680537L, 195115L, 1325434L, 
870810L, 399998L, 1755193L, 39280000L, 2612835L, 2643000L, 5660759L, 
201188L, 1855899L, 2393468L, 278147L, 1291212L, 4082284L, 7051999L, 
15342597L, 35949L, 1606024L, 2448224L, 91427L, 1054759L, 121252L
), data_t_1 = c(162991L, 1278341L, 433815L, 315210L, 13280222L, 
144622L, 280714L, 184286L, 349399L, 441119L, 51123L, 1112556L, 
3240105L, 2467071L, 9515093L, 1686249L, 461023L, 927146L, 507399L, 
3561613L, 1929679L, 69828L, 622204L, 242895L, 1968208L, 8453347L, 
2467278L, 92742L, 1194816L, 1197646L, 547391L, 1845368L, 38550000L, 
4555685L, 5158000L, 6324394L, 241155L, 2420718L, 3180737L, 5768459L, 
1548164L, 4318517L, 9019486L, 14386327L, 35934L, 2044495L, 2598361L, 
135402L, NA, 336379L), data_t_2 = c(308060L, 1746234L, 2473258L, 
249339L, 14327822L, NA, 259635L, 455523L, 370401L, 455568L, 40985L, 
1321363L, 1449123L, 1928196L, 9661314L, 2367151L, 375473L, 1228645L, 
420788L, 99090L, 1976669L, 150717L, NA, 271140L, 3995829L, 8166218L, 
2175989L, 87277L, 1097358L, NA, 788137L, 1695421L, 39801000L, 
4372307L, 142504L, 3439554L, 114912L, 3388745L, 2834629L, 7034688L, 
1462947L, 4537559L, 8000863L, 12737184L, 150782L, 2333824L, 2710126L, 
254109L, NA, 1140718L), data_t_3 = c(406563L, 1769192L, NA, 212706L, 
14351345L, NA, 238441L, 888216L, 255452L, 488883L, 97195L, 1106291L, 
35366L, 1388799L, 7684599L, 2425390L, 4152L, 953383L, 542362L, 
NA, 2499211L, 167215L, NA, 145238L, 8647716L, 7866078L, 1874842L, 
NA, 2158139L, NA, 736088L, 1425002L, 44633000L, 3831578L, 159060L, 
2781418L, 85171L, 3159740L, 2463385L, 8038953L, 1346105L, 4578169L, 
6277353L, 12501786L, 61561L, 2966259L, 2733420L, 298200L, NA, 
697574L)), .Names = c("year_t", "data_t", "data_t_1", "data_t_2", 
"data_t_3"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Data frame 2:

```
structure(list(year = c("1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", 
"1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", 
"2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
"2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", 
"2017"), multiplyer = c("45.5158032501528", "48.6069799436928", 
"51.8742543668362", "54.9525837849594", "58.208266424359", "60.8678441879755", 
"63.7398405992427", "66.7189155811034", "69.093337017433", "70.4552205020515", 
"71.7476020867733", "73.4052195938148", "75.9256001089651", "78.6512027854055", 
"81.0624649001436", "83.5261426387297", "86.064670544112", "88.9637193712232", 
"92.0911276421223", "94.6577354325631", "98.5156636153782", "98.2319416221847", 
"100.000000000000000000000000000000", "103.196146412241", "105.720324344817", 
"107.209444053708", "107.047696829365", "106.511964511277", "106.296094858635", 
"108.375335054149")), .Names = c("year", "multiplyer"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Apologies! My exxpected output would actually be a formula or a sparse matrix, however I think the formula would be better. i will add it to the original question now.

Comment: I have changed the question for a better approach.

Comment: @user113156 the desired output numbers don't seem to match the data you provide so it's difficult to know what you're after.  Also it appears you think for 2010 that there will be 3 multipliers but you only have 1 for that year in the 2nd table.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just made up the desired output numbers for illustration purposes

Comment: @user113156 What I'm saying is that this problem is perfectly clear to you but you're not making it perfectly clear to others.  I can almost guarentee you that if you make the problem understandable you'll get a prompt response that helps...on the flip side if it is muddy it will never get an answer.  Also note that the smaller (less data) that you can make the problem...the easeir it is to reason about.

Comment: Thanks, you are right that the problem is clear for me and it is difficult to explain what I am trying to do. I will make a quick edit and add an additional explanation.

Comment: I have added a working example to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first table is named df1 and the second df2 this should give you what you're after:

```
library(tidyverse)


df1 %>%
    mutate(
        year_t = as.integer(as.character(year_t)),
        id = seq_len(n())
    ) %>%
    gather(time, measure, -c(year_t, id)) %>%
    mutate(
        time = as.integer(gsub('^[^0-9]+', '', gsub('t$', 't0', time))),
        year = as.character(year_t - time)
    ) %>%
    left_join(df2, by = 'year') %>%
    mutate(
        multiplyer = as.numeric(multiplyer),
        output = measure / multiplyer,
        time = paste0('weighted_t_', time)
    ) %>%
    select(id, time, output) %>%
    spread(time, output) %>%
    left_join(df1 %>% mutate(id = seq_len(n())), by = 'id') %>%
    select(year_t:data_t_3, everything())
```

I had to do a lot of converting types because they are mismatched between tables or not stored in optimal ways (e.g., factor rather than integer for year or multiplyer stored as character).

Comment: Thanks! this worked perfectly and (it took me some time) I managed to get it to work on my data! Really appreciate it, thanks again!